# Custom UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uilabel

I am creating a custom `UIView` that should contain a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`
here is the class for it.

```
import UIKit

class AnswersCustomView: UIView {
    var myImageView = UIImageView()
    var myLabel = UILabel()
    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        addLabel()
        bringSubviewToFront(myLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    func addLabel(){
        let myViewFrame = self.frame
        myLabel.frame = myViewFrame
        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myLabel.center=self.center

        addSubview(myLabel)
    }


}
```

whenever I create an instance of this view from a `UIViewController`. 
the `UIView` get added but it seems that the `UILabel` is not.
any reason for that?

Comment: You should reference your IBOutlet from your Xib file to your AnswersCustomView.

Comment: The label should have a frame of the view's bounds - not the view's frame

Comment: Here is my sample project about CustomView, very easy to understand https://github.com/khuong291/Swift_Example_Series/tree/master/CustomView

Comment: How have you tested and debugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment one problem could be that the label has an incorrect frame.
As stated in Apple documentation the frame is:

> This rectangle defines the size and position of the view in its
>   superview’s coordinate system. You use this rectangle during layout
>   operations to size and position the view. Setting this property
>   changes the point specified by the center property and the size in the
>   bounds rectangle accordingly. The coordinates of the frame rectangle
>   are always specified in points.

The label you created is subview of the instance `AnswersCustomView`, not the `AnswersCustomView` superview, so you should set the label's frame as its superview bounds.

The other one is autolayout: you are not using it. I don't know how you create the AnswerView, bit if its initial frame is zero your label will remain zero, you should add it and set constraints or at least autoresizing masks.

Another one can be if you are creating the view in a xib, in this case `iniWithCoder` is called and here you are not placing any label.

To simplify views debugging Apple has added a new tool that displays your view hierarchy in 3d https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6